# Persist Username visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have a textbox and i am writing a text changed event, whenever the text is changed, i am saving the username in properties.settings.default.username....now i want to write this username into my textbox when the application is run the next time... my question is how do i write this onto my config.xaml file, so that it prints the last used username into that textbox when the application is next used... ?

```
private void tbx_Username_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) //ip
{          
     Properties.Settings.Default.username = tbx_Username.Text; //ip
     tbx_Username.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.username; //ip
     Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); //ip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Loaded event from the Window or UserControl that the Username is on. Something like:

```
private void Window_Loaded( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    tbx_Username.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.username;
}
```